# what is a commandline argument?

Tags: python

I am a newcomer to python (also very sorry if this is a newb question but) i have no idea what a command line argument is. when `sys.argv` is called, what exactly are the arguments? Any help with understanding this would be a great service.

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to ask. The arguments are the things passed to your program on the command line, example: `python myfile.py these are the arguments`. Are you asking where they are stored, or how, or what?

Comment: This is not a Python question.  This is a Linux (or Windows) question that applies to **all** programming languages.  Please add the tag for your OS so we can link to your OS documentation that explains the command line.

Comment: `argv` usually stands for "argument values". (There's also a `argc` for argument count.) How do you call `sys.argv`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try running this program:

```
import sys
print(sys.argv)
```

You should see results similar to this:

```
% test.py
['/home/unutbu/pybin/test.py']
% test.py foo
['/home/unutbu/pybin/test.py', 'foo']
% test.py foo bar
['/home/unutbu/pybin/test.py', 'foo', 'bar']
% python test.py foo
['test.py', 'foo']
```

So, you see `sys.argv` is a list. The first item is the path to (or filename of) the script being run, followed by command-line arguments.

Comment: Another great answer from @unutbu

Answer (score 6):

Given the command `myscript.py arg1 arg2 arg3`, the arguments are arg1, arg2 and arg3. sys.argv will also include the script name (i.e. myscript.py) in the first position.

[Command line arguments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Arguments) are not specific to python.

Answer (score 0):

The command line arguments are the strings you type after a command in the command line, for instance:

```
python --help
```

Here `--help` is the argument for the `python` command, that shows a help page with the valid command line arguments for the `python` command.

In a python program, you have access to the arguments in `sys.argv`, so let's say you started a python script like this:

```
python myscript.py -x -y
```

When `myscript.py` starts, `sys.argv[1]` will have as value the string '-x' and `sys.argv[2]` will have as value the string '-y'. What you do with those arguments is up to you, and there are modules to help you easily define command line arguments, for instance [argparse](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html).

Answer (score 0):

Command line arguments are parameters you type after the script name. Eg. if you type: `python test.py arg1`, the first argument is arg1.

For examples, take a look at [jhu.edu](http://www.jhu.edu/pfleming/compbio/files/byte/ch14s02.html).

Answer (score 0):

The arguments are usually used as a way of telling the program what it should do when it is run.

If I had a program named writefile.py, and I wanted the user to tell it which file to write, then I would run it with `python writefile.py targetfile.txt`.  My sample writefile.py:

```
import sys

file = open(sys.argv[1], 'w') # sys.argv[0] = 'writefile.py' (unutbu's answer)
file.write('ABCDE')
file.close
```

After running this, I'll have a file named targetfile.txt with the contents "ABCDE".  If I ran it with `python writefile.py abcde.txt`, I'd have abcde.txt with the contents "ABCDE".